# Weird situation with fixed div in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-position

I have a fixed div on top of my site but when scrolled in Google Chrome, div disappears. When I change the tab, div is in the right place but when I scroll again, it disappears again.

You can see it from http://www.fillyo.com just scroll down in chrome and you'll see what I mean (both right bar and top bar disappears when scrolled)

I searched but couldn't find anything related to this.

**FIRST IMAGE**: On page load, you can see the gray bar on top and texts on right bar which has position:fixed

**SECOND IMAGE**: when scrolled, gray bar is still there but can't be seen just like the right bar (only adsense code stays on the right place as it can be seen on second image)
[image: On page load, you can see the gray bar on top and texts on right bar which has position:fixed]

[image: when scrolled, gray bar is still there but can't be seen just like the right bar]

Comment: Working fine on my up-to-date version of Chrome running on Windows XP. Maybe add a 'left' position too?

Comment: left:0; doesn't change anything :/

Comment: works fine for me too, Chrome 21.0.1180.79, Win7

Comment: 21.0.1180.79 with win7 but id doesn't work for me lol. What am I missing?

Comment: @Pabuc Can you add some code or screenshots?

Comment: @VukasinManojlovic just added 2 images, 1 on page load, 1 after scroll. The gray div and right div can't be seen after scroll.

Comment: Works in Ubuntu with Chrome 21.0.1180.79 and on Windows 7 with the same version on my machines, I don't see the effect you are describing,

Comment: I can also confirm that there are no problems in Chrome 21.0.1180.79 (Win XP here). You'll need to post your HTML and CSS so we can see what the problem might be.

Comment: Check [this](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/18489/position-fixed-doesnt-work-in-all-google-chrome/p1). The best is to try that code in your browser... I can't find anything helpful. Some people also have the problem like yours, but none of them fix them (or I can't found).

Comment: The most interesting part is, everything goes ok when I remove google adsense code from the right panel.